# How can I add a page to a StackNavigator with a state change? (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation, stack, navigator

I need to add pages to a StackNavigator after the StackNavigator has already been initialized with pages. How can I add pages/screens to it at any given time? Can I hook up to a state maybe?

Not really sure what the best way to go at this is...

Answer (score 0):

One method for doing this is to have the page/screen template imported and ready to go, and then fill it dynamically with the following when your state changes.

`this.props.navigation.setParams({...yourDynamicProps})`

If you need to choose a template your can use a Case/Switch statement or if/else conditional to dynamically change the template name.

`this.props.navigation.navigate("DYNAMIC_STRING")`

Comment: So like have the page already in there but the contents not loaded? In my case I am loading a group of pages from Firebase and so I wouldn't know how many pages that is or what they need until that data is retrieved.

Comment: If the template is loaded, you can set params (data) with `this.props.navigation.setParams({})` and then in the template, pull those props with `this.props.navigations.state.params`. That way your template can be dynamic depending on what you download. If you need to make multiple pages you might be able to create a new StackNavigator in your render() or componentWillUpdate() methods. It would work, but I'm not sure if it's best practice. I would just try to make one template and make it dynamic enough that it renders different components when given certain data.